# Force delete Session records for the current login User : Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

**What is it about ?**

I am using `Sessions` table that keep accumulating the Current user login sessions in `Sessions` table.

**What's the issue ?**

Instead of manually deleting the record after login, Is there any way to force Laravel 5.2 to delete all current User associated records based on user_id ?

Is there anything to do with changing `'lottery' => [2, 100],` to `'lottery' => [1, 1],` ?

Comment: Login refreshes it/updates it.

Comment: I means, it keep adding new records in `sessions` table. Is there any way to force `Laravel 5.2` to delete all current User associated records based on `user_id` ?

Comment: well a simple delete query based on user_id !?

Comment: I tried to write it in `write` method which is in `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler.php` but not working. May be there is any inbuilt way to keep only one record per user ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the correct approach to do so in case of multi user logins. Below is my code. Please provide feedback

**Created a Model**

```
class Session_Model extends Model
{
    protected $table = "sessions";
}
```

**Modified the method to write/Update the record in `Sessions` Table. You can find this mothod in this class: **

> \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler.php

---

```
public function write($sessionId, $data)
{
    $payload = $this->getDefaultPayload($data);
    if ($this->exists) {


        /*****Remove other then current login in user Session*****/
        \App\Models\User\Session_Model
                ::where('id', '!=', $sessionId)
                ->where('user_id', '=', $payload['user_id'])
                ->delete();


        $this->getQuery()->where('id', $sessionId)->update($payload);
    } else {
        $payload['id'] = $sessionId;

        /********Remove all previous sessions of a user***************/
        \App\Models\User\Session_Model
                ::where('user_id', '=', $payload['user_id'])
                ->delete();


        $this->getQuery()->insert($payload);
    }

    $this->exists = true;
}
```